# How can I make the user set location manually on map in Flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter, location, flutter-layout

I have a "set location on map" feature that I'm supposed to implement, how can I achieve something like that with flutter.

I want to open a map showing user's current location, then he can drag the marker to set it to the location he wants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a package named as: google_map_location_picker

[google_map_location_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/google_map_location_picker)

[image]